# What is the main diff b/w Custom Renderer and Effects in Xamarin Forms? How to create them?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to create Custom Renderer and effects in Xamarin Forms and how to decide when should i use which one?

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/introduction

Answer (score 1):

Better use a custom renderer if you need to override methods of a platform-specific control (e.g. add buttons onto the native DatePicker control).

Or else, you can use effects for simple customizations of a platform-specific control (e.g. remove borders for all entries).

Quoted from the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/introduction#why-use-an-effect-over-a-custom-renderer) :

> Effects simplify the customization of a control, are reusable, and can be parameterized to further increase reuse.
>
> Anything that can be achieved with an effect can also be achieved with a custom renderer. However, custom renderers offer more flexibility and customization than effects.